# AttributeError: module 'folium' has no attribute 'Rectangle'

Tags: python, folium

I've been using Folium, tried versions 0.5.0 and 0.11.0, in a Python notebook in IBM Watson studio. folium.Map and folium.Circlemarker work fine, but folium.Rectangle fails... is there a way around this? Or is the function for adding a rectangle different now? Code that generated error in title is below

```
folium.Rectangle(bounds=[[39.78,-105.05],[39.68,-105.05],[39.68,-104.94],[39.78,-104.94]], color='#ff7800', fill=True, fill_color='#ffff00', fill_opacity=0.2).add_to(mapD)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, please double check your folium version using `folium.__version__`. (in python)

According to [changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/CHANGES.txt), you can use `folium.CircleMarker` after 0.4.0.

> 0.4.0
>
> - `PolyLine`, `Circle` and `CircleMarker` are set to leaflet's defaults and
>   accepted all `Path`'s optional arguments (ocefpaf #683 and #697)

Similarly, you can use `folium.Rectangle` only after 0.6.0.

> 0.6.0
>
> - `Rectangle` and `Polygon` were renamed and set to leaflet's defaults.
>   Both now accepted all `Path`'s optional arguments (ocefpaf #722)

So if your folium version is lower than 0.6.0, you should use `folium.features.RectangleMarker` instead of `folium.Rectangle`.

If your folium version is really 0.11.0, but you cannot use `folium.Rectangle` still, please check if you correctly imported folium. (using `import folium`)

Comment: Thank you so much! I just ended up using the features command with 0.5.0 and it worked :-)